# Function that Returns a Set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was having a talk with one of my computer science teachers and he claimed that there are no functions that can return a variable number of parameters in mathematics (outside of extremely abstract fields).  I haven't had much experience with these topics, so instead I took this as a challenge and decided to try the following:

`f:Z->{Z}
f(x)={yϵZ|0<y<x}`

Where 'f' should return the set of all integers in between the 0 and 'x' that aren't negative.

I understand that this isn't STRICTLY defining a function with multiple return values (such as a potential function that solves the quadratic equation), but is it still a series of valid mathematical statements that would provide a workaround counterexample?

(also, any information about functions that return variable-size tuples would be helpful)

EDIT: I might've overstated my professor's position on this, so please don't take that so far into consideration...

Comment: For the last point: consider a function $f\colon X\to Y$, where $Y= \bigcup_{d=1}^\infty \mathbb{N}^d$.

Comment: Your professor overstated the case. He probably should have said something more like "You don't often see such a function in algebra or calculus."

Comment: In ZFC everything is a set, so all functions return sets.

Comment: Ooh, not really.  That has returned one *set* which is a single parameter.  I'd say further than all functions return *one* parameter.  Which intern may be a set of variable elements so... I don't think the professor is being as deep as he thinks he is.  I don't want to be cynical or dismissive but I'd say the professors statement is not worth stating.  And I think you did a good job showing the statement wasn't that deep or perplexing with thought.  Yes, I'd call yours a counter-example to the statement having any significance, but not to it being literally true.

Comment: A Christopher Moore fan, are you?

Comment: As fleablood said, fundamentally every function "takes" one input from the domain and "returns" one output from the codomain. But of course that codomain could be any old set, and could combine "single values" (say, numbers) alongside ordered pairs or triples of values. There's no deep distincion between a function mapping to such a codomain and a function that returns variable numbers of values.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, when someone says "mathematics doesn't do X" or "mathematics can't do Y" or something similar, what is *actually* going on is either **(1)** "mathematics doesn't do X and Y in the very specific way that I imagined, and I never really put much thought as to how one might do it differently" or **(2)** "While I'm using the words, I don't mean what they usually mean, or only mean for my assertion to be applied to a narrow setting and I forgot to actually tell you what that setting is".

Comment: What does he mean by returning a parameter?

Comment: I guess he means *returns a value*. He's also misusing terminology: functions, especially "functions " in programming languages, don't *return parameters*, they *take* or *have* parameters and return *values*.

Comment: Though it has been about 5 years since I have initially posted this, I now know that this is easily doable in python using the pack/splat operator.  @BrianO These terminological points are merely pedantic, and we could simply use 'inputs' and 'outputs' for penultimate clarification.

Comment: 'inputs' and 'outputs' would have been fine. You were quoting a professor, who I thought should have had the pedantry thing down better.  I wasn't sure if you meant mathematical or software functions. The pack/splat operators let you be flexible about  "arity" - how many arguments a function takes. You can define your function f as a set-valued function, so that `f(y)` returns `{x for x in range(1, y)}`. `

Comment: @BrianO I had paraphrased my professor at the time, not quoted.  Regardless of to whom the pendantry would be attributable, however, it doesn't matter since such pedantry is irrelevant and unnecessary to clarity the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the object that you are trying to describe is called a [set-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), and they are quite common in, for example, economics (though economists prefer to call them correspondences).

Formally, we have a function

$$ f: X \to 2^Y. $$

Here, $f$ maps each member of $X$ into a subset of $Y$. ($2^Y$ denotes, as usual, the power set of $Y$.) So it is *strictly* a function that maps $X$ into $2^Y$. Of course, it is **not** a function from from $X$ into $Y$. (If $f$ were singleton-valued, however, we can make the obvious identification of $f$ with a function from $X$ into $Y$.)

In fact, I think you point out a good example of a set-valued function. Suppose $$ f:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to 2^{\mathbb C}, $$ where $f$ takes the real numbers $(a,b,c)$ and returns the roots of the quadratic $ax^2 +bx + c = 0$. $f$ is clearly well-defined as a set-valued function on $\mathbb C$, but you'd need to do some extra work if want $f$ to be a classical function.